# SVN and Apache - are there any advantages?

Tags: windows, apache, svn, http

I just hooked together Apache and SVN.  Not sure what I was expecting, but something a little more exciting, I suppose.  Makes me wonder what's the use - according to [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html), in the comments:

> Setting up svn in Apache is more complicated...what does that get us? Some kind of web UI? Use of port 80?

and it turns if I want a UI, there's several PHP interfaces already written...which begs the question, are there any advantages to Apachifying an SVN installation?  Security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, I setup Apache as a front-end for my various VCS for:

- https communication (point-to-point encryption)
- Authentication:

  - you can demand for a "Valid-user" for your service you expose through http
  - you can link that authentication to your company LDAP in order to use the same login/password than for your Windows session
- Service listing (you can aggregate many services behind your domain, `https://yourdomain/svn` being just one of them: `https://yourdomain/jira`, `https://yourdomain/fisheye`, ...)

Comment: Great!  You've just validated the last few hours of work :)  Cheers.  Will wait a bit for other input.

Comment: Yet another advantage are secured HTTPS repositories. But I prefer GIT these days. Much more faster and handy than SVN.

Comment: @Maksym - that seems to be the current of discussion in the various blogs I've been lurking around, distributed control and all that.  Will attempt another day.

Comment: I didn't mention the obvious "repository browsing" mentioned in http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd